# How disable a js file in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript

I do several similar things in several Js files. I want to deactivate some js files and enable others in another file within a conditional statement.
How can I do this?

for example:

```
// My files: | javascript_1.js | - |  javascript_2.js |

if( flag == true ){
// disable javascript_1.js
}
else{
// enable javascript_2.js
}
```

Comment: Once a script has been loaded and parsed, it can't be removed or "disabled". What you can do, is to conditionally load your scripts, but I suspect your problem can be solved with functions.

Comment: There are plugins to disable a specific script
I do not know how these work. But I did not test them and got to know them today https://superuser.com/questions/278590/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-specific-js-script-from-a-specific-website      @Teemu

Comment: Yes, plugins can do that, and you can disbale a script in the DevTools, but it's not possible to do it on the code of a web page, because the [script is not reachable to the DOM](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#execute-the-script-block) after it is parsed, you simply can't refer it with JS.,

Comment: If you have a practical design problem you're trying to solve by enabling and disabling scripts, you might introduce your desing and ask for the specific problem, as this smells more like an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answers. @Teemu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refresh the page when you need new code from one file.

If you do not have a problem with page refresh.

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Using the following:

If you click **`Add Bootstrap`** bootstrap will be added dynamically. If you click **`Remove Bootstrap`** will be removed dynamically;

You can check by input field and button styles

```js
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
    let targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none"; //determine element type to create nodelist from
    let targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none"; //determine corresponding attribute to test for
    let allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement);
    for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
    if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
        allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]); //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
    }
}

function createjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    let fileref;
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}

function addB() {
    createjscssfile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css','css');
    createjscssfile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js','js');
    createjscssfile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js','js');
}

function removeB() {
    removejscssfile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css','css');
    removejscssfile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js','js');
    removejscssfile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js','js');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addB()">Add Bootstrap</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeB()">Remove Bootstrap</button>

<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
</div>
```

#### Hope this helps :)